# How to tell whether a Feynman diagram is $t$-channel or $s$-channel by looking?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, definition, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

By looking at a diagram, how does one tell whether it represents a $s$-channel process or a $t$-channel process i.e., without finding the amplitude? I'm familiar with [Mandelstam variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables) but I've trouble understanding what a $s$-channel or $t$-channel process would mean and how to tell the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to check the agreement beetween fermions/antifermions and the directions of their arrows.

Take this for example:

[image]

You can label all the fermions $e^-$ and it's t-channel. If you label the top left and bottom right $e^-$ and the other two $e^+$, it's s-channel.

Comment: If the diagram represents $e^-$–$e^-$ scattering then it doesn't follow *either* of the usual conventions for labeling the axis. It would have time increasing *down* the page.

Comment: Still gives the same amplitude.

Comment: Sure, but a reader could easily be confused by it. It's a small correction to refer to positron-positron scattering instead of electron scattering and then the example is plausible for one the common conventions.

Answer (score 1):

For a two-body scattering process denoted by $$a_1(p_1)+a_2(p_2)\to a_3(p_3)+a_4(p_4)$$ the tree-level Feynman diagrams can be classified into three categories. A tree-level scattering diagram is called the *$s$-channel*, the *$t$-channel* and the *$u$-channel* process if the squared 4-momentum of carried by the mediator is $s=(p_1+p_2)^2$, $t=(p_1-p_3)^2$ and $u=(p_1-p_4)^2$ respectively. Thus by identifying the 4-momentum of the exchange particle, it is easy to decide whether the diagram is $s$, $t$ or $u$-channel.

Reference: Mark Thomson's lecture notes (Page 13)
[https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/partIIIparticles/handouts/Handout_1_2011.pdf](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Ethomson/partIIIparticles/handouts/Handout_1_2011.pdf)