# $s$-channel, $t$-channel and $u$-channel

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, feynman-diagrams

I'm studying the $e^{+}e^{-}\rightarrow f^{+} f^{-}$ scattering, where $f$ is a generic fermion ($f^{\pm}\not=e^{\pm}$). I know the process is described by the $s$-channel, but why the $t$-channel or the $u$-channel can't describe it? How can I understand which channel to use to describe the process?

Comment: Have your written down the Feynman diagrams involved in all *s,t,u* processes?

Comment: see the answer here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112957/whats-the-difference-between-t-channel-and-s-channel-in-particle-physics

Comment: Related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/330717/how-to-tell-whether-a-feynman-diagram-is-t-channel-or-s-channel-by-looking