# In QED why there's just the $s$ or the $t,u$ diagrams in these processes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering

In examples I've seem form QED considering the process $e^+e^-\to \mu^+\mu^-$ the books show only the $s$ diagram and no $t,u$ diagrams. In the Moller scattering, $e^-e^-\to e^-e^-$ there's just the $t,u$ diagrams and no $s$ diagram.

I'm trying to understand the particle-particle scattering in a simpler theory, namely Yukawa theory, and I can't understand what diagrams are there and aren't there.

For this matter I'm trying to understand these two cases which are given in examples.

Why in one case there's just $s$ channel and the other there is just $t,u$ channels?

Is this something to do with the fact that the interaction lagrangian has $\psi\bar{\psi}$ in it times the potential $A_\mu$?

What is the correct reasoning here?

Answer (score 4):

Just think! What would the charge be for the   particle whose propagotor would appear  in the $e^-$ $e^-$  s-channel diagram?  Is there such a particle in QED? And can an $e^+$ and a $\mu^-$ annihilate  to give a photon in the u- or t-channel?

Comment: So the issue is all with charge conservation? Since two electrons enters the vertex, a charge $2e$ is entering, hence a charge $2e$ must leave, so a photon can't be there, so the vertex which is necessarily two fermions and a photon can't be formed. So when building the diagrams, at each vertex we must make sure momentum **and** charge is conserved right?

Comment: @user1620696 Homework assignment: $e^+e^- \to e^+e^-$